# Telerik Kendo UI MVC - Using Wizard - how to validate a partial view form before the next step

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, kendo-ui, telerik

I have a simple Wizard control which loads partial views.  All I want to do is validate the partial view before going on to the next step.  When I tried jquery validate I got an error `validate is Undefined`.  I am not able to find much help as I want to use the data annotations for the validation.  Any help is apprecited.

```
Business.cshtml

@using Kendo.Mvc.UI
@model Reverberate.BLL.Model.Form.Application.BusinessOnboardingModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Business Onboarding";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<style>
    .wide {
        width: 95%;
    }

    .field-validation-error {
        color: red;
    }
</style>



    <!-- Wizard -->
    @(Html.Kendo().Wizard()
        .Name("wizard")
        .Events(ev => ev.Select("onSelect"))
        .Events(ev => ev.Done("onDone"))
        .LoadOnDemand(true)
        .ReloadOnSelect(false)
        .Steps(s =>
        {
            s.Add<Reverberate.BLL.Model.Form.Application.BusinessOnboardingModel>()
            .Title("Business Profile")
            .ContentUrl(Url.Action("_BusinessProfile", "Onboard"))
            .Buttons(b =>
            {
                b.Next().Text("Next");
            });

            s.Add<Reverberate.BLL.Model.Form.Application.BusinessOnboardingModel>()
            .Title("Business Financial")
            .ContentUrl(Url.Action("_BusinessFinancial", "Onboard", Model))
            .Buttons(b =>
            {
                b.Previous().Text("Back");
                b.Next().Text("Next");
            });
            s.Add<Reverberate.BLL.Model.Form.Application.BusinessOnboardingModel>()
            .Title("Business Address")
            .ContentUrl(Url.Action("_BusinessAddress", "Onboard", Model))
            .Buttons(b =>
            {
                b.Previous().Text("Back");
                b.Done().Text("Submit");
            });
        })
    )

<script type="text/javascript">
    var dataPartial1;
    var dataPartial2;
    var currentStep;

    function onSelect(e) {

       
        var form, contentUrl;

        if (e.step.options.index < currentStep) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        else {

            if (e.step.options.index == 1) {
                form = $('#frmPartialBusinessProfilefrmPartialBusinessProfile');
                dataPartial1 = form.serialize();
                contentUrl = '@Url.Action("_BusinessFinancial", "Onboard",Model)';
            }
            else if (e.step.options.index == 2) {
                form = $('#frmPartial2');
                dataLesions = form.serialize();
                contentUrl = '@Url.Action("_BusinessAddress", "Onboard",Model)';
            }
            if (!form.valid()) {
                alert('not valid');
                e.preventDefault();
            }
            else {
                alert('valid');
                e.step.options.contentUrl = contentUrl;
            }
            alert('done');
        }


        currentStep = e.step.options.index;
    }

    function onNextStep(e) {
        if (e.step.options.index == 2) {
            openDoc();
        }
    }

    function onDone(e) {

        var form = $('#frmMain');

        if (form.valid()) {
            form.submit();
        }

    }

    var onAddMainSuccess = function (result) {

        if (result.error) {
            alert(result.error);
        }
    };


</script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.13.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
```

_BusinessProfile.cshtml

```
@using Kendo.Mvc.UI
@model Reverberate.BLL.Model.Form.Application.BusinessOnboardingModel

<form id="frmPartialBusinessProfile" name="frmPartialBusinessProfile">
    <div style="width: 45%; float: left; border: 1px solid black" id="BusinessInfoEntry">
        <h3>Business Profile</h3>
        <fieldset>
            <legend></legend>
            <ol>
                <li>
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.BusinessProfileModel.BusinessName)
                    <br />
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.BusinessProfileModel.BusinessName, new { maxlength = 200, @class = "wide" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.BusinessProfileModel.BusinessName)
                </li>
                <li>
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.BusinessProfileModel.FederalTaxId)
                    <br />
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.BusinessProfileModel.FederalTaxId, new { maxlength = 20 })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.BusinessProfileModel.FederalTaxId)
                </li>
                <li>
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.BusinessProfileModel.BusinessStartDate)
                    <br />
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.BusinessProfileModel.BusinessStartDate, new { @type = "date", @class = "form-control datepicker", @Value = Model == null || Model.BusinessProfileModel.BusinessStartDate == null ? null : Model.BusinessProfileModel.BusinessStartDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.BusinessProfileModel.BusinessStartDate)
                </li>
                <li>
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.BusinessProfileModel.Industry)
                    <br />
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.BusinessProfileModel.Industry, new { maxlength = 200, @class = "wide" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.BusinessProfileModel.Industry)
                </li>
                <li>
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.BusinessProfileModel.Sector)
                    <br />
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.BusinessProfileModel.Sector, new { maxlength = 200, @class = "wide" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.BusinessProfileModel.Sector)
                </li>
                <li>
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.BusinessProfileModel.StateOfFormation)
                    <br />
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.BusinessProfileModel.StateOfFormation, new SelectList(ViewBag.States, "Value", "Text"), "Select State", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", id = "StateOfFormationList" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.BusinessProfileModel.StateOfFormation)
                </li>
                <li>
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.BusinessProfileModel.EmployeeCount)
                    <br />
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.BusinessProfileModel.EmployeeCount, new { @type = "number", @class = "wide" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.BusinessProfileModel.EmployeeCount)
                </li>
                <li>
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.BusinessProfileModel.BusinessStructure)
                    <br />
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.BusinessProfileModel.BusinessStructure, new SelectList(ViewBag.BusinessTypeList, "Value", "Text"), "Select Business Type", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", id = "StateOfFormationList" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.BusinessProfileModel.BusinessStructure)
                </li>
            </ol>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
</form>
```

BusinessProfileModel.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Reverberate.BLL.Model.Form.Application.BusinessOnboarding
{
    public class BusinessProfileModel
    {
        public BusinessProfileModel() { }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "The business name is required.")]
        [DisplayName("*Business Name")]
        [StringLength(250)]
        public string BusinessName { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("*Federal Tax Id / SSN")]
        [StringLength(15, ErrorMessage = "Please enter a valid federal tax id or SSN")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter the federal tax id or SSN")]
        public string FederalTaxId { get; set; }

       

        [DisplayName("*Business Start Date")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter the business start date")]
        public DateTime BusinessStartDate { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "The industry is required.")]
        [DisplayName("*Industry")]
        [StringLength(500)]
        public string Industry { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "The sector is required.")]
        [DisplayName("*Sector")]
        [StringLength(500)]
        public string Sector { get; set; }


        [DisplayName("*State of Formation")]
        [Validation.InputValidation.ValidState(ErrorMessage = "This does not appear to be a valid US State.")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "The State of Formation is required.")]

        public string StateOfFormation { get; set; }
        

        [DisplayName("*No of Employees")]
        [Validation.InputValidation.ValidState(ErrorMessage = "Number of Employees.")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Supply the number of employees.")]
        public int EmployeeCount { get; set; }


        [Validation.InputValidation.ValidBusinessType(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a valid business structure")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "The business structure required.")]
        [DisplayName("*Business Structure")]
        public string BusinessStructure { get; set; }
    }
}
```

BusinessOnboardingModel.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Reverberate.BLL.Model.Form.Application.BusinessOnboarding
{
    public class BusinessOnboardingModel
    {
        public BusinessProfileModel BusinessProfileModel { get; set; }

        public BusinessFinancialModel BusinessFinancialModel { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Comment: After an entire day, I sort of figure out the issue.  For some reason whcih still unknow Jquery cannot find a form in a form.  And then I had my jquery scripts out of order.